# AWS codebuild define timestamp as a global variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

i am trying to define timestamp as a global variable but it doesn't seem to work. When i try to echo the time stamp value i get $(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M) instead of the date and time value. I want to be able to get something like this when i echo out. 2022-07-20-23-24

```html
version: 0.2
env:
  variables: 
    TIMESTAMP: $(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M)
  parameter-store:
    USERNAME: "username"
    PASSWORD: "secret"
   
Phases:
  install:
    runtime-version:
    python:3.8  
  
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo '$TIMESTAMP'
  
  build:
    commands:
      - echo '$TIMESTAMP'
```

Comment: It does not work, because its not even a valid `buildspec.yml`. Thus I would start by making sure that the `buildspec.yml` you use has actually a valid format in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know of to make it work, is by saving timestamp in a tmp file. For example:

```
version: 0.2
env:
  parameter-store:
    USERNAME: "username"
    PASSWORD: "secret"
   
Phases:
  install:
    runtime-version:
    python:3.8  
  
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo $(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M) > /tmp/timestamp
      - echo $(cat /tmp/timestamp)
  
  build:
    commands:
      - echo $(cat /tmp/timestamp)
```

Comment: This definitely work, but will not really help me because i'd like to store the timestamp on a variable and then write it on to the .env file so that i can be able to access the variable and use it on my python code.

Comment: @saum You can read from `/tmp/timestamp` into variable. If you don't want to do this, then you can possibly achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the variable during the install phase.

**echo-datetime.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "$DATETIME"
```

**buildspec.yml**

```yaml
version: 0.2

phases:
    
  install:
    commands:
      - DATETIME=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")

  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo $DATETIME
      - chmod +x ./echo-datetime.sh

  build:
    commands:
      - ./echo-datetime.sh
        
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo $DATETIME
```

Partial log from CodeBuild

```
[Container] 2023/01/13 14:52:44 Entering phase INSTALL
[Container] 2023/01/13 14:52:44 Running command DATETIME=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")

[Container] 2023/01/13 14:52:44 Phase complete: INSTALL State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2023/01/13 14:52:44 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2023/01/13 14:52:44 Entering phase PRE_BUILD
[Container] 2023/01/13 14:52:44 Running command echo $DATETIME
2023-01-13-14-52-44

[Container] 2023/01/13 14:52:44 Running command chmod +x ./echo-datetime.sh

[Container] 2023/01/13 14:52:44 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2023/01/13 14:52:44 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2023/01/13 14:52:44 Entering phase BUILD
[Container] 2023/01/13 14:52:44 Running command ./echo-datetime.sh
2023-01-13-14-52-44

[Container] 2023/01/13 14:52:44 Phase complete: BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2023/01/13 14:52:44 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2023/01/13 14:52:44 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2023/01/13 14:52:44 Running command echo $DATETIME
2023-01-13-14-52-44
```